# Stopwatch app counter going too fast

Tags: ios, swift

I am just learning iOS and programming in general and I am making a very basic iOS stopwatch app. I got the stopwatch working however, when I press start more than once the timer begins to go faster so that it is no longer a second long ([gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4o6f.gif)). Also, my formatting seems to be off for the seconds part, if you have any suggestions there it would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var minuteLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!

var timer = NSTimer()

var second = 0

var minute = 0

func updateTime() {
    do{
        if second != 59
        {
            second++

            secondLabel.text = ".\(second)"
        }
        else
        {
            second = 0

            minute++

            secondLabel.text = "." + String(format:"$%.2f", second)
            if minute < 10
            {
            minuteLabel.text = "0\(minute)"
            }
            else
            {
                minuteLabel.text = String(format:"$%.2f", minute)
            }
        }
    }

}



@IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    second = 0
    minute = 0
    secondLabel.text = ".00"
    minuteLabel.text = "00"

}

@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You shouldn't use a timer to measure time. Just save the start date and get the time interval since that date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not invalidating `timer` when `startButton` is called, so tapping "Start" multiple times is creating duplicate timers which call the same function, `updateTime`. Change `startButton` to look like this:

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !timer.valid
    {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

}
```

For your second question about the formatting, you need to put a condition to check for the seconds being less than 10, similar to what you did with the minutes. You would put a 0 in front of the seconds. In `updateTime`:

```
if second < 10
{
     second++

     secondLabel.text = ".0\(second)"
}
else if second <= 59
{
     second++

     secondLabel.text = ".\(second)"
}
else
{
     ...
}
```

See [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Wow, that's so simple! Thank you! Right before you commented I figured out how to do it using a boolean! Any clue on why my formatting does not work?

Comment: @Rcub3161 You're welcome! See my edit about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired formatting by using `"%02d"` instead of `%.2f`. Using `%.2f` will ensure 2 digits after the decimal point which is not true in your case (you have both `second` and `minute` as integers). Also you can use get away with using one label (e.g., `timerLabel`) as shown below:

```
var second = 0
var minute = 0

func updateTime() {

    let dFormat = "%02d"

    second++
    if second == 59{
        minute++
        second = 0
    }

    let s = "\String(format: dFormat, minute):\String(format: dFormat, second))"
    timerLabel.text = s

}
```

Hope this helps!